# How to know if model is Overfit in case of random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I followed the tutorial on random forest as found here...

https://pythondata.com/forecasting-with-random-forests/

The last statement output is around 70%

```
r2_score(y_train[:, None], X_train_predict.reset_index().values)
```

The score on train data is good enough. But what about test data score? Is this correct?

```
r2_score(y_test, rgr.predict(X_test.to_frame()))
-0.08512482162571144
```

If this score is correct, why does the test score is so low compared to train data score?

Comment: Looks like your test data isn't representative of the train data. You can look at individual variable distributions between train and test. If test data is drastically different from train, model will not perform well. For Overfitting evaluation we plot the train and evaluation results. While train error will continue to drop. But test scores start to rise after a certain point, that is ideally the stopping point beyond which it overfits. Refer to the last graph in https://towardsdatascience.com/overfitting-vs-underfitting-a-complete-example-d05dd7e19765

Comment: Practically, nobody uses the R-squared as a performance measure for anything else other than linear regression; I strongly suggest to use some other performance metric from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) appropriate for regression (e.g. mean squared error - MSE, which the post author mentions but does not demonstrate).